# Why this recursive code treats its input int argument differently when it is 2 that any other number?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how the tower-of-hanoi code mechanics.
I reduced the full code to this piece of code to understand its behviour:

---

```
def hanoi(disks, source, helper, destination):
    if (disks == 1):
        print('Disk {} moves from tower {} to tower {}.'.format(disks, source, destination))
        return
    hanoi(disks - 1, source, destination, helper)

disks = 3
hanoi(disks, 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

---

Can someone please explain why I get different outputs when disks is equals to 3 versus 2?

The output for disks = 3: Disk 1 moves from tower A to tower **C**.
The output for disks = 2: Disk 1 moves from tower A to tower **B**.

Thanks!

I would expect the funtion hanoi(disks - 1, source, destination, helper) to output the first line in both cases when the input disks is 3 and 2, but for some reason it is executed only when disks = 2 and not for any other value.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This code prints one line given either `disks = 3` or `disks = 2`.

Comment: The line is only printed when disks == 1, else a recursive call is made, with 1 disk removed and the helper and destination tower switched; when you start with 2 disks, only 1 call is made before disks == 1; when you start with 3 disks, 2 calls are made, so the helper and destination are switched twice, hence the difference in the output.

Comment: Thanks. Then why for 4 disks I get the same output of 3? and not the same output of two given the helper and destination are switched three times?

Comment: You must have made a mistake somewhere; your code gives me the same output for all even values of disks.

Comment: You are right, my bad.
Thanks @Swifty !! all clear now

Answer (score 0):

```py
def hanoi(disks, source, helper, destination):
    if (disks == 1):
        print('Disk {} moves from tower {} to tower {}.'.format(disks, source, destination))
        return
    hanoi(disks - 1, source, destination, helper)
    print('Disk {} moves from tower {} to tower {}.'.format(disks, source, destination))
    hanoi(disks - 1, helper, source, destination)
```

This modified function will print out the individual moves for each disk, and you'll see the expected output for disks equals to 2 and 3.